# Sitecore image upload versioning in Media Library

Tags: sitecore-client, media-library, versions

How I like to add versioning for an image in media library in Sitecore 8.0.
Please suggest me how can I do the version of an image?

Answer (score 4):

When you upload a new picture you need to fill checkbox : Make media library versionable :

[image: enter code here]

More details you can find here: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/media_items/using_media_items/upload_a_file_to_the_media_library

Comment: Q1) Is it recommended for using the version of an image when used in the media library?

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore supports to use `Unversioned` and `Versioned` templates for Media Items. All these templates you can find `/sitecore/templates/System/Media`

[image]

Versioning for Media items the same as a standard items versioning. You can easily to set Publishing Restrictions and use your Media item.

```
<setting name="Media.UploadAsVersionableByDefault" value="false" />
```

If you set it to `true`, item will be created only in one default language version. This media item will use a versioned template `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned/File` template and if it is false, then it will use `/Sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/File` template and create media Item in all those languages which exist under `/Sitecore/system/languages`.

Comment: Is it recommended for using version of an image when used in the media library?

Comment: @Amit By default Sitecore uploads media as unversioned data. In order to have different media data for different languages you need to upload media as versioned. Otherwise you won't be able to have different data for the same media item. Even if you change unversioned template to versioned.

Comment: @Amit Also you can use Sitecore Rules for show specific image base on your condition. But if you want to use versioning with Publishing Restrictions you should remember, that OOTB items will not publish at set time automatically unfortunately, you have to schedule it to publish (even then there are some issues around schedule timers that may mean it's not exact).

Comment: You can default this to on in the sitecore.config by setting the value to true. The default is false which is not versionable. <setting name="Media.UploadAsVersionableByDefault" value="false" />